# How to apply permission at user level in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am working with Opencart version 1.5.1.3. i've make some changes and customization in user group and user modules.The problem i'm facing from permission at user level.

When admin create any common user and after that the user get logged-in and go to the **system->user** tab ,then they can see all users list including admin and super admin. actually i dont want to give access to the users to view all users and edit it.

so how can i make permission for that, and display only users which are created by that particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure they have their own user group. Secondly, edit the user group, and make sure there's no checkbox next to the "user/user" value in both the access and modification lists, then save